# How to generate a javascript alert with a small string message using Selenium Java WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to generate or popup a java-script alert window with a string message from within the Selenium Java program while it is running. I read somewhere that we can execute javascript within Selenium as like..
You can directly execute javascript on a hidden element and set the attribute:

```
WebDriver driver;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('auth_login_password').setAttribute('value', val );");
driver.ExecuteScript(string.Format("document.getElementById('cred-password-inputtext').value='{0}';",password));
```

How do I modify to write out a java-script alert? If it was feasible, I would like to use it as a debug tool too.

Comment: http://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html

 google it?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing this. I would learn how to debug programs using the IDE that you use. That will provide better debugging tools once you learn how to use them.

Comment: I had considered that. But my technology mix is Selenium with Java, executed as groovy project. The debug facility for groovy code with in Eclipse(Neon) IDE is not available to my knowledge. I tried couple of suggestions, but not productive. Only thing, I have at my hand is 'println() statements from groovy code, which are OK, when the program runs with out throwing exceptions. Once exceptions were thrown, there is no real help, as the println statements does not get printed until the line point, the exceptions are thrown. They stop way early.

Answer (score 2):

For creating the javascript alert you can use this:

```
public void triggerAlert(String alertMessage){
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("alert('"+alertMessage+"');");
        }
```

But you should add the parameter to chromeOptions for not accepting the alert by default

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines in your code where you want to receive an alert:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("alert('I am an alert box!')");
```